# Using sqlite SEE with MVVMCross

Tags: encryption, plugins, sqlite, mvvmcross

I potentially want to use the encrypted version of sqlite [(link)](https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki). Essentially to use sqlite encryption enhancements (SEE) you need to build a version of the sqlite3.dll.

I am using MVVMCross. Is it possible to use the MVVMCross plugins with this version of the ddl, rather than the default version installed on iOS and android. If so how do you do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing MvvmCross [plugin](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/tree/master/SQLite-PCL) doesn't reference the encrypted dll. With that you can't switch them out easily right now i think.

You could just copy the code into your project and use the encrypted version of SQLite. Another option would be to make a fix to be able to switch SQLite version that the plugin uses, make a pull request so MvvmCross can release an update for the current plugin.